# How can I change the background image on the macOS switch users screen, not the lock screen

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, mac, monterey

I have a query regarding the customization of the macOS switch users screen. I've been exploring ways to change the background image specifically on the switch users screen, not the lock screen.

My lock screen image change is working fine with background image change.

[image]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I think you cannot do this in Monterey

Comment: I am trying to change the background image on the switch users screen. Currently, I am using macOS 12.7.1 Monterey. This is the login screen for multiple user accounts where we choose which account to log in to.